How to enforce type on Vue generic component for multiple properties
When defining a generic Vue component, it appears that the resulting type of the generic is the union of all arguments.  Is it possible to limit this so the type of all properties must match?
For example, a generic select component:
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends string">
  // We want to enforce modelValue & options come from the same set of possible values
  defineProps<{
    modelValue?: T
    options: readonly T[]
  }>()

const emit = defineEmits<(e: 'update:modelValue', val?: T) => void>()
// Have a <select with options
</script>

I would hope that with the above component, I would get an error with the below usage as the two types being passed do not intersect
<script setup lang="ts">
type ValidOptions = "Big"|"Small"|"Medium"
const value = ref<ValidOptions>("Small")
</script>
<template>
  <!-- options & modelValue have different types here -->
  <MySelect :options="['Chicken','Little'] as const" v-model="value" />
</template

However, when defining it in this way the generic type ends up being the union of all types: "Chicken"|"Little"|"Big"|"Small"|"Medium", and so no error is reported

You can type your select like this:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<component :is="MySelect<ValidOptions>" :options="['Chicken','Little'] as const" v-model="value" />


Ideally, I want the parent component to define the valid options, so I use MySelect and have the compiler validate that in each instance the value & options match (since I just fixed a bug where they didn't).  At the moment, I suspect that isn't possible, maybe the answer is to create type-specific wrappers of the underlying component.

@FrozenKiwi updated the answer, a wrapper isn't necessary

That is fantastic - you're a legend Mr Nenashev :-)

You can specify your generic with @vue-generic. See #4971.
<!-- @vue-generic {ValidOptions} -->
<MySelect :options="['Chicken','Little'] as const" v-model="value" />

